# Select buttons like in digital ocean

Tags: javascript, html, css

somebody know a js/css libary, or a keyword how it is called? I'm searching for a while for that button select element like digital ocean, see picture :-)
Where I can click and they got selected and so on, I think it is pretty nice

[image: Digital Ocean Dashboard (Create new Droplet)]

Comment: There's lots of button styling libraries out there.  I'm not sure if Digital Ocean is using one or if they just custom coded it themselves.  Use the Google Developers Tools panel to look at the HTML and CSS stylings for those elements.  Something like this is farily easy to do unless you're new to CSS and HTML.  If you are, I think you should take the time to code it yourself by analyzing their code through the inspector.  Relying on libraries will make you a weaker developer in the long run if you don't generally understand what's going on underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's not a button. It can be a simple div or a list element. Here is a sample code.

You can add content into each `li` element to emulate the required list. You can also use `div` or `span' for the same purpose.

```js
$(".button-container li").click(function(){
   console.log("list");
   $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.button-container li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-radius:5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  position:relative;
  margin:10px;
}

li.selected
        {
           background:#4183D7;
          color:white;
          border:2px solid #4183D7;
        }
span
{
  display:block;
  color:#444;
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  font-size:10px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="button-container">
  <li>some content
  <span>
    Some other content
    </span>
  </li>
   <li>some content
  <span>
    Some other content
    </span>
  </li>
   <li>some content
  <span>
    Some other content
    </span>
  </li>
   <li>some content
  <span>
    Some other content
    </span>
  </li>
   <li>some content
  <span>
    Some other content
    </span>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```